# Drag Shadow is shown away from by Drag object in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

In my application i used drag & drop to arrange some TextViews.  While dragging drag shadow is not shown near dragging object (rounded in the picture is the position of the drag shadow).  How to position to near to drag item.  I tried below code

```
 private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
          if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
 }

 class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
        Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
        Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
          int action = event.getAction();
          switch (event.getAction()) {
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
              TextView tv1 = (TextView) event.getLocalState();
              TextView tv2 = (TextView) v;
              String s1 = tv1.getText().toString();
              String s2 = tv2.getText().toString();
              tv1.setText(s2);
              tv2.setText(s1);
              tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
              if(!event.getResult())
                  ((View)event.getLocalState()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          default:
            break;
          }
          return true;
        }
      }
```

[image]